# Why does this code compile in the Coderbyte editor, but not in my own IDE?

Tags: java

I am referring to this scanner question program https://coderbyte.com/editor/Find%20Intersection:Java

There:

```
 public static String FindIntersection(String[] strArr) {
    return strArr[0];
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) {  
    // keep this function call here     
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print(FindIntersection(s.nextLine())); 
  }
```

How can `s.nextLine()` be equal to `FindIntersection(String[] strArr)` you cant convert to scanner readline to array can we!

This code throws array in my java IDE

Answer (score 0):

That code wont compile.

It seems that Coderbyte simply replaces `s.nextLine()` with the input before it is compiled. You can see this in the error output when you change the input into something that wont compile:

```
Main.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
    System.out.print(FindIntersection(new tring[] {"1, 3, 4, 7, 13", "1, 2, 4, 13, 15"})); 
                                          ^
  symbol:   class tring
  location: class Main
```

If you rename `s` to `scanner` it wont be able to replace it and you will get the error message that you are supposed to get:

```
Main.java:14: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to String[]
    System.out.print(FindIntersection(scanner.nextLine())); 
                                                      ^
```

I'm not sure why they chose to do it this way. It is very misleading.

Comment: Hackerrank and LeetCode don't resort to these kinds of shenanigans.  Just sayin'...